# 'AVG' and 'SUM' functionality in MongoDB, any tips?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm a relative newbie to MongoDB, but from what I've read there are various methods to going about finding averages and sums of values in a MongoDB database, with various benefits and drawbacks for each.

I'm primarily asking for a method of finding the sum of a selection of values, and the average of a selection of values, in an as efficient (fast) method possible.

The documents in the collection being queried resemble this structure (with a lot of other fields):

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('4e650107580fd649e5000005'),
    "date_added": ISODate("2011-09-05T00:00:00Z"),
    "value": 1500
}
```

Precalculating things like sums is, in my application, not always possible, because the selection of values to be summed can change (based on date ranges - e.g. between a start date and an end date, what is the average).  This is a similar problem with precalculating averages.

From what I've read, MapReduce is definitely not ideal for real-time (i.e. on demand) lookup, so that seems to be out of the question too.

At the moment I'm querying the collection in this way: (note: this is using `pymongo`)

```
response = request.db['somecollection'].find(
    {
        'date_added': {
            '$gte': date_start,
            '$lte': date_end
        }
    },
    {
        'value':1
    }
).limit(500)
```

Then doing the calculation in Python using a `for` loop over the response.  The limit of 500 results is arbitrary, to keep it from become too slow.  I'm only retrieving the value, and none of the other fields.

Is this the most efficient method of doing this calculcation, or are there other methods to accomplish what I need?

**Caveats:**

- I can't use the `group` function because I will probably be using sharding in the future
- I can't use MapReduce because it's a function which will be used on-the-fly by users
- I can't precalculate a lot of my sums/averages because the selection of values to sum/average is almost always different
- I have looked around stackoverflow and the web to try and find recommendation on how to do this kind of thing, and it's fairly open-ended

**EDIT:**

I should point out that the number of documents returned from the query I posted above could be anything from 1 document to hundreds, but will probably have a maximum number of returned documents of about 150 (average of about 60 or 70)

Answer (score 4):

Give map-reduce a try, it's probably not as slow as you think.  I've used it for real-time aggregation over some large data sets, and although it's sometimes not lightning fast, it's more often fine.  It's best if you can filter down the size of the initial data you're aggregating, e.g.:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(m, r, { query : { year: 2011 } });
```

If you need to speed things up even more, consider distributing the data over a sharded cluster.  Then the map-reduce processing can be scaled out across multiple shards running in parallel.

Comment: I'm definitely going to be experimenting more with MapReduce. I know it will vary between datasets/queries/etc., but in your case was it fast enough to not really be noticeable to the user (i.e. under half a second)?

Comment: Varying between 500-5000ms, but some of the data sets were quite large (100M+ docs), so needed a busy/progress indicator, but fast enough.  Map-reduce performance should also improve when the JavaScript engine is upgraded from single-threaded SpiderMonkey to V8.

Comment: Ah, that sounds promising. At the moment my dataset is very small (measured in the thousands, not the millions), although this will grow over time.

Comment: Don't forget that you can provide a query to Map-Reduce to limit the inputs. M-R is still not as scalable as direct querying (Javascript limitations require that only one Map-Reduce or other Javascript task can be run at a time), but with a query which filters results to the about 150 you mention above, it should be pretty fast.

Comment: @Chris V8 will not improve concurrency or the single threaded nature of JavaScript tied functionality in MongoDB. It is likely to improve performance though.

Comment: @Remon I'd argue the opposite :) I reckon the most improvement will come from better concurrency, running V8 in isolation mode, rather than improved raw JavaScript engine performance which is probably now comparable.

Comment: @Chris, I definitely agree the ability to run concurrent JS contexted jobs within MongoDB *would* improve performance but the work being done by 10gen to replace the current JS engine with V8 will not do or enable this. Talked to a 10gen engineering regarding this very issue.

Answer (score 3):

**MongoDB notes**

OK, so Map/Reduce and aggregation have some serious issues currently.

Big caveat: **the MongoDB instance can only have one "javascript engine" instance**. This means that you cannot run two simultaneous Map/Reduces on the server. And you only get one core for running the map-reduce.

In the case of what you are doing, you're basically "rolling your own" M/R. The downside is the extra network traffic. The upside is that you can now throw more cores at the problem (from the web-servers).

**Your key question**

> I can't precalculate a lot of my sums/averages because the selection of values to sum/average is almost always different

There is no general method for optimizing "all possible" queries. If you want the system to be able to sum and aggregate along every field for every range, then you will eventually find a set of fields/ranges that are too big.

The way to "solve" this is to reduce the set of fields and ranges.

So keep daily / hourly counters and sum over those counters. At the least you reduce the number of documents you need to scan in order to answer your query.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is:

1. If it possible precalculate everything you can precalculate.
2. If you need aggregate data by date ranges and aggregation should work as quick as possible then use map/reduce + sharding to distribute calculation across multiple machines.

But in same time mongodb guide say:

> The price of using MapReduce is speed: group is not particularly
>   speedy, but MapReduce is slower and is not supposed to be used in
>   “real time.” You run MapReduce as a background job, it creates a
>   collection of results, and then you can query that collection in real
>   time.

So it sounds like mongodb is not best solution for real time data aggregation.

Comment: I'm definitely pre-calculating all the values I can.  Unfortunately I'm confined to one machine, at least at first, so I can't spread it across multiple machines.  In my example, does the number of returned documents affect the speed enough to consider using MapReduce? (I added the average number of documents returned to the bottom of my question)

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is slated to get native aggregation functions for things like sum/avg/min/max in version 2.1.1 (currently slated for Nov 1, 2011). For more detail and status see the issue at: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-447